# Paranamer error due to missing debug information in compiled class files

Tags: java, parameters, websphere, bytecode, paranamer

I am trying to run a spring batch on application deployed on WebSphere. When I run the batch using Eclipse all runs fine but when I run the same batch in deployed application on WebSphere it gives error

```
com.thoughtworks.paranamer.ParameterNamesNotFoundException: Parameter names  not found for executeMethod
    at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer$TypeCollector.getParameterNamesForMethod(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:209)
```

I checked source code of paranamer `BytecodeReadingParanamer` class and it says

```java
if (!collector.isDebugInfoPresent()) {
    if (throwExceptionIfMissing) {
        throw new ParameterNamesNotFoundException("Parameter names not found for " + methodName);
    } else {
        return Paranamer.EMPTY_NAMES;
    }
}
```

I believe it means that the Java class was not compiled with debug information (`-g` flag?) on WebSphere whereas in Eclipse, I have this information.

How can I correct this error on WebSphere? Do we have a add debug information in Java compiled classes flag?

Comment: anyone please!!

Comment: The option to include parameter names into the compiled class files is distinct from debug options. With `javac`, it’s the `-parameters` option. But I can’t say anything about Websphere…

Comment: The code says if (!collector.isDebugInfoPresent()), so it means on websphere debug info is not present. How to add it in websphere ? When we run same application in eclipse, it runs fine. Is it because in eclipse class files, debug information is present ?

Comment: You should say how you build your deployable. Maven , Gradle, Ant, etc ...
I guess the problem is how you compile classes

Comment: You are right. This was the issue of compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank @minus the issue was indeed with the compiler as there was some bug in the compiler server. There was not anything wrong with paranamer or code itself. The bug of compiler had to be fixed.